# Turn down sharpness laptop display

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card

How can i turn down the sharpness on a laptop screen at 1080p? my old laptop was 1080p and didnt have sharpness i have 2 cards 1 nvidia 940m and the other is a intel hd 4600 please help cause this sharpness annoys me.

Comment: Is there an Nvidia control panel you can access to adjust settings? It is either in the control panel or right click context menu from the desktop.

Comment: Yes but it dosent have much options on it

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows 7,
Right-click anywhere on desktop. Select "Screen resolution" from the drop-down menu and click OK.

Comment: This would fix it but dont want to be on a lower res just want it to be less sharp.